# How do you split a string based on delimiter not being between two characters in php regex?

Tags: php, regex, perl, google-maps, delimiter

I've tried a bunch of stuff but nothing works.  I have a string and I want to split the string by a comma `,` but don't split if the comma is between a *bracket*, a *brace*, or a *double* or *single quotation mark*- for this specific case to maintain the complete iframe (which is destroying everything) string.  Below is the string ...

```
class : putmeincoach, 
 id : random_id,  
   responsive : {   [ type= text ;  html = "&lt; iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/myplaces?ctz=480&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=34.009394,-118.488514&amp;spn=0.020687,0.020921&amp;t=m&amp;z=16"&gt; &lt; /iframe &gt;" ;  ]  }
```

I just want

```
Array (
   [0] = 'class : putmeincoach',
   [1] = 'id : random_id',
   [2] = 'responsive : {   [ type= text ;  html = "&lt; iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/myplaces?ctz=480&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=34.009394,-118.488514&amp;spn=0.020687,0.020921&amp;t=m&amp;z=16"&gt; &lt; /iframe &gt;" ;  ]  } '
```

Can I do this using preg_split or preg_match with some generalized regex pattern? Lemme also mention that not having the comma between the double quotation marks is really the most important

Comment: Is there a new line after each comma?

Comment: Hey Thanks for the edit Ben.  How did you do that by the way? And how do I learn?

Also nhahtdh - Newlines dont matter match.  I just separated them for readability of the people looking at the questions.

Comment: @JoeMcmorgan, on the box where you enter the text for your question, take a look at the buttons above it

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Hey appreciate the tip nhahtdh, but Im trying to stay away from other data structures like JSON and do php regex.  With that said I couldnt detect an example that include the comma in the decoded JSON strings on the page.  This is not JSON fyi, its just a structure I set up for that takes user input in a specific fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP:

```
<?php
$input = '
    class : putmeincoach, 
    id : random_id, 
    responsive : {   [ type= text ;  html = "&lt; iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/myplaces?ctz=480&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=34.009394,-118.488514&amp;spn=0.020687,0.020921&amp;t=m&amp;z=16"&gt; &lt; /iframe &gt;" ;  ]  }, 
    testsinglequotes: \'hello world\', 
    testdoublequotes: "hello hello"';
$pattern = '/ 
    \b(\w+)\s*:   # capture the word before the colon 
    \s*(          # start capture group match after the colon
        {[^}]*}\s*|     # match everything between braces  OR
        "[^"]*"\s*|      # match everything between double quotes OR
        \'[^\']*\'\s*|   # match everything between single OR
        [^,]*           # match everything up to the comma 
        )         # end capture group
    (?:,|$)       # match comma or end of string (non-capture group) 
    /x';
preg_match_all($pattern ,$input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
?>
```

Output PHP 5.3.13:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => class : putmeincoach,
            [1] => id : random_id,
            [2] => responsive : {   [ type= text ;  html = "&lt; iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/myplaces?ctz=480&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=34.009394,-118.488514&amp;spn=0.020687,0.020921&amp;t=m&amp;z=16"&gt; &lt; /iframe &gt;" ;  ]  },
            [3] => testsinglequotes: 'hello world',
            [4] => testdoublequotes: "hello hello"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => class
            [1] => id
            [2] => responsive
            [3] => testsinglequotes
            [4] => testdoublequotes
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => putmeincoach
            [1] => random_id
            [2] => {   [ type= text ;  html = "&lt; iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/myplaces?ctz=480&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=34.009394,-118.488514&amp;spn=0.020687,0.020921&amp;t=m&amp;z=16"&gt; &lt; /iframe &gt;" ;  ]  }
            [3] => 'hello world'
            [4] => "hello hello"
        )

)
```

Regex is your friend

Comment: Lol this is sooo complex..any helpful tips into how this works?

Comment: I think it doesn't get any better than that. +1 from me.

Comment: Thanks mrhobo but this doesnt seem to work in PHP because I have to wrap the pattern in "/ and /" and you have quotes in there that are not escaped. This is what I put it with flags and everything.. preg_match_all("/\b(\w+)\s*:\s*({[^}]*}\s*|\"[^\"]\"\s*|'[^']'\s*|[^,]*)(?:,|$)/gm" ,$searchme, $matches); 

and it fails prolly cus I had to escape the quotes.  You mentioned it in your comment before though...

Comment: Your answer still has problems escaping and therefor doesnt work but Ill give you points because its at least valid on the link you showed me earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
^(class.*?,).*?(id.*?,).*?(responsive.*,?)$
```

using http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/ and this worked. The tricky thing is to use the lazy matching for .* in the first two groups and for the ',' in the last.

You will need to adapt this to PHP since the regex handling is a bit different, I think.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without including 'class','id', or 'responsive'?  These are just random keywords and I could have more or less(and different ones) depending on what input I get..

Comment: Yes, see mrhobo's answer ;)